# Apache rewrite backreference variable not accessible after first use

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have come across a situation that seems odd to me. It seems that backreference variables when building apache rewrite rules get lost after the first use.

My requirement is changing an old URL pattern to conform to a new path pattern, e.g:

```
www.example.com/documents/newsletter/newsletter-issue-50.htm
```

to become

```
www.example.com/sites/default/newsletter/50/English/newsletter-issue-50.htm
```

As you can see, the new URL pattern needs to have the issue number specified in 2 places.

My rewrite rule is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^documents/newsletter/newsletter-issue-(.*).htm$ http://www.example.com/sites/default/newsletter/$1/English/newsletter-issue-$1.htm [R=301,L]
```

When I use this rule, I still get a 404 because the resultant URL misses to replace the second "$1" with the issue number , in this case "50". What I get is

```
http://www.example.com/sites/default/newsletter/50/English/newsletter-issue-.htm
```

I have used [this](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) test site and it confirms that the second backreference variable is not being evaluated at all. Am sure am missing something here, since it should be a simple rule to put in place.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your rule works fine for me, on apache 2.2.22

Comment: Yes, it seems to work now..... I must have been doing something wrong for it not work the first time round...

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, I works in the rewrite tester if you surround with 2 sets of parenthesis:

```
RewriteRule ^documents/newsletter/newsletter-issue-((.*))[.]htm$ http://www.example.com/sites/default/newsletter/$1/English/newsletter-issue-$1.htm [R=301,L]
```

I have also escaped the file extension prefix

Comment: It seems the rewrite tester has a bug of some sort. I will see if I can alert the developers to look into what could be the issue.